# Ожидание завершения цикла асинхронных вызовов c#

Tags: c#

Есть цикл, который асинхронно скачивает много файлов:

```cs
privare void MyLogic(...) {

   int start = 5, end = 150;
   string filepath = @"somepath", url=@"someurl", ext = ".zip";

   for (int i = start; i<= end; i++) 
   {
      LoadFile(filepath + @"\" + i.ToString("D4"), url + i.ToString() + ext);
   }

   //вот тут я хочу выполнить обработку только после того, как все загрузки будут завершены

}


private void LoadFile(string url, string path)
{
   try
   {
       using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
       {
           client.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) =>
           {
               Console.WriteLine(url + " success");
           };

           client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), path); //асинхронная загрузка
       }
   }
   catch
   {
       Console.WriteLine(url + " error"); //досадно, но продолжаем
   }
}
```

После цикла я хочу обработать на уровне файловой системы то, что скачалось. Как мне переписать код, чтобы точно понять в какой момент успешная загрузка всех файлов завершилась?

Comment: `void` не ожидаются, делайте `Task` и запускайте через `async/await`.

Comment: `await ` тут не совсем, то что нужно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ можете привести пример как это в связке с WebClient должно выглядеть? Там есть другой метод `DownloadFileTaskAsync ` но я не очень понимаю, как он работает

Comment: `private void LoadFile` -> `private async Task LoadFile`. Далее как минимум `client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), path);` -> `await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync (new Uri(url), path);`. У вас будет тем самым `Task`, которую можно дождаться. Запускать вы ее тоже должны через `await` - `await LoadFile(...);`. Метод `MyLogic` тоже лучше сделать таском, но для начала добавьте ему `async` перез `void`. Все, у вас должно теперь дожидаться выполнения загрузки. P.S. `WebClient` не стоит использовать для новых приложений.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ но если я везде поставлю await загрузка станет синхронной, это не равносильно отсутствию async вообще? Мне надо знать, когда все файлы параллельно загрузятся, не важно в каком порядке.

Comment: Советую вам почитать про `async/await` и попробовать для начала)

Comment: Я бы использовал класс `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` и нормальную асинхронность, запуская каждый процесс таском, при этом ограничивая количество одновременно загружаемых файлов, иначе можно забить все сокеты и заблочить пользователю сеть, или вызвать суровые лаги. При этом каждый файл грузить и писать на диск как Стрим с буферизацией, иначе можно забить всю память и уронить приложение с Out of Memory. Представьте, что вам надо асинхронно сачать 1000 файлов, по гигабайту каждый. @EvgeniyZ, напишите ответ, ваша же тема :)

Comment: @aepot Решение я дал вроде как, этого должно автору хватить. По поводу загрузки файлов - это уже другой вопрос, который не относиться к текущему. За репутацией я не гонюсь, можете ответ дать какой пожелаете, хоть дословно копируйте мои слова выше, я не против)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И так для начала, вам надо изменить `LoadFile` сделав его `Task`, а не `void`. Например, так

```
private async Task LoadFileAsync(string url, string path)
{
   try
   {
       using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
       {
           client.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) =>
           {
               Console.WriteLine(url + " success");
           };

           await client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), path); //асинхронная загрузка
       }
   }
   catch
   {
       Console.WriteLine(url + " error"); //досадно, но продолжаем
   }
}
```

А вот с `MyLogic` есть три варианта:

1) Выполняем все загрузки по одной по очереди, но асинхронно

```
private async Task MyLogic(...) 
{    
   ...

   for (int i = start; i<= end; i++) 
   {
      await LoadFileAsync(filepath + @"\" + i.ToString("D4"), url + i.ToString() + ext);
   }

   DoAfter();     
}
```

2) Запускаем все 100500 загрузок сразу и ждём их окончания

```
private async Task MyLogic(...) 
{    
   ...

   var taks = new List<Task>(); 
   for (int i = start; i<= end; i++) 
   {
      Task task = LoadFileAsync(filepath + @"\" + i.ToString("D4"), url + i.ToString() + ext);
      tasks.Add(task); 
   }
   await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

   DoAfter();     
}
```

3) Всё таки запускать неизвестное какое количество задач одновременно не очень прилично. И для этого придуман паттерн *Throttling* (ссылка на википедию). Конечно, его можно реализовать самому, а можно воспользоваться библиотекой *Task Parallel Libraray.Dataflow* (ссылка на нюгет)

```
private async Task MyLogic(...) 
{    
    ...

    var block = new ActionBlock<int>(
        i => LoadFileAsync(filepath + @"\" + i.ToString("D4"), url + i.ToString() + ext),
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50 });

    for (int i = start; i<= end; i++) 
    {
       block.Post(i);
    }

    block.Complete();
    await block.Completion;

    DoAfter();     
}
```

Comment: Я бы еще указал, как запустить асинхронный `MyLogic` из синхронного кода правильно, например хотя-бы `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. А то автор получит при вызове метода то, с чего начал.

Comment: Спасибо большое, в точности то разъяснение, которое было нужно

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример с полной асинхронностью кода и использованием `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`.

Консольное приложение, .NET Core 3.1 (C# 8.0)

**Полный код приложения с комментариями**

```csharp
class Program
{
    // HttpClient создается один раз на все время работы приложения
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    struct DownloadParams // структура для параметров загрузки
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string FilePath { get; set; }
    }

    // асинхронный Main, обратите внимание!
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<DownloadParams> downloads = new List<DownloadParams>(); // новый список загрузок
        int start = 5, end = 150;
        string filepath = @"somepath", url = @"someurl", ext = ".zip";

        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) // заполнение списка загрузок
        {
            downloads.Add(new DownloadParams { Url = url + i.ToString() + ext, FilePath = filepath + "/" + i.ToString("D4") });
        }

        try
        {
            await DownloadFilesAsync(downloads); // загружаем
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка при загрузке: " + ex.Message);
        }

        // здесь код, который надо выполнить после завершения всех загрузок.
        // при этом, все файлы уже записаны на диск, можно открывать и обрабатывать
    }

    // асинхронно загружает весь список с ограничением на количество одновременных загрузок
    private static async Task DownloadFilesAsync(List<DownloadParams> downloads)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Запуск загрузки.");
        int maxTasks = 20; // максимальное количество одновременно работающих задач
        using SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxTasks);
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (DownloadParams download in downloads)
        {
            // ждать, если достигнуто максимальное количество одновременно работающих задач, пока их не станет меньше
            await semaphore.WaitAsync();

            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await DownloadAndSaveFileAsync(download); // загрузить файл
                semaphore.Release(); // сообщить, что задач стало меньше
            }));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks); // ждать завершения всех задач
        Console.WriteLine("Загрузка завершена.");
    }

    // асинхронно загружает один файл
    private static async Task DownloadAndSaveFileAsync(DownloadParams download)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Начата загрузка из: " + download.Url + ", и сохранение в: " + download.FilePath);
        try
        {
            using HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(download.Url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false);
            responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // бросить исключение, если сервер вернул ошибку

            using FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(download.FilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None); // новый файл

            using Stream stream = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); // загрузка данных

            await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream); // запись на диск
            Console.WriteLine("Файл " + download.FilePath + " успешно загружен и сохранен.");
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Если с асинхронным `Main` сложно, то вот обычный синхронный

```csharp
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<DownloadParams> downloads = new List<DownloadParams>(); // новый список загрузок
    int start = 5, end = 150;
    string filepath = @"somepath", url = @"someurl", ext = ".zip";

    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) // заполнение списка загрузок
    {
        downloads.Add(new DownloadParams { Url = url + i.ToString() + ext, FilePath = filepath + "/" + i.ToString("D4") });
    }

    try
    {
        DownloadFilesAsync(downloads).GetAwaiter().RetGesult(); // загружаем
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка при загрузке: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Слова поток и thread лучше бы убрать, так как они могут ввести в заблуждение

Comment: @4per согласен, исправлено

Comment: @aepot спасибо большое за пример, будем разбираться с `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` но уже в новых проектах. Жаль не могу отметить оба ответа как правильные.