# Операция над файлами из очереди в нескольких потоках C#

Tags: c#, распараллеливание

Есть каталог с файлами, которые надо обработать.
Есть массив из 4х потоков.
Эти 4 потока должны обработать эти файлы.
Файлы у меня добавлены в очередь и должны выбираться из очереди и выполнятся свободным потоком.
Как организовать работу с массивом потоков - я не до конца понимаю.
Если не сложно, объясните, как можно сделать.

```
int countfiles; //количество файлов в каталоге
        int countthreads = 4;
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[countthreads];
        Queue<string> filesqueue = new Queue<string>();
        foreach (string file_to_read in filelist)
        {
            filesqueue.Enqueue(file_to_read); //добавить в очередь файлы из каталога
            countfiles++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < countthreads; i++)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Используйте Channel из пакета System.Threading.Channels вместо очереди.

Comment: Вот буквально сегодня писал [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1112924) для многопоточной обработки. Посмотрите в то место, где я использовал `SemaphoreSlim` и почитайте про него. Там задача немного отличается, не всего 4 потока, в которые друг за другом можно закидывать задачи, а просто огриничение на максимальное количество одновременно запущеных потоков.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class MainClass
{
    private List<List<string>> ListOfListsOfFiles;
    private var ListToWorkWithTasks;

    public void MainMethod()
    {
        int countfiles; //количество файлов в каталоге
        int countthreads = 4;
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[countthreads];
        ListOfListsOfFiles = new List<List<string>>(countthreads);

        for (int i = 0; i < filelist.Count; i += countthreads)
        {
            // Прошу простить за этот кривой цикл - не сильно
            // долго над ним думал
            for (int j = i; j < i+4; j++)
            {
                ListOfListsOfFiles[j-i].Add(filelist[j]);
            }
        }

        Task[] arrayOfTasks = new Task[countthreads];
        for (int i = 0; i < countthreads; i++)
        {
            int index = i; // Так надо.
            // Таски стартуют не сразу - могут взять обновлённый i, а
            // последний Task и вовсе выйдет за пределы массива, потому что i
            // уже будет равен 4
            arrayOfTasks[index] = Task.Run(() => 
            {
                VoidForTaskArray(ListOfListsOfFiles[index]); 
            });
        }
        Task.WaitAll(arrayOfTasks);

        // Дальнейшая работа
    }


    private void VoidForTaskArray(List<string> fileAddressList)
    {
        // Общий алгоритм для каждого потока

        // Запись результатов в ListToWorkWithTasks
    }
}
```

Использовал `List` а не `Queue`, так как о `Queue` узнал только что

Comment: спасибо вам большое за ответ!
Только мне по заданию именно методами класса Thread это нужно реализовать, но, я думаю, Task похожим образом работает, попробую изменить под threads))

Comment: [Может пригодиться](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1099825/thread-join-вызывается-раньше-начала-работы-потока) - там хоть ответ и дан для ``Task``, однако вопрос задан для ``Thread``, и за исключением того, что автор вопроса не учитывал, что асинхронный поток во время запуска может для ``thread.Join`` вернуть управление, в вопросе достаточно полезный код. В случае, когда запускается всего 4 потока и не ``async``, этой проблемы, по идее, быть не должно

Comment: ваш ответ очень полезен! Благодарю))

Comment: @Anatoly пожалуйста уберите избыточный код из ответа и поясните, почему вы решили задачу именно так. И все же лучше использовать `Queue`, в этом нет ничего сложного.